# Calling Templated C++ Method based on Runtime Logic

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I often run into the problems associated with SubType Polymorphism, I'm looking for an elegant solution I may not already be aware of.

Here is a simple inheritence hierarchy:

```
struct BaseClass { 
    virtual ~BaseClass() = 0; 
    std::string name; 
};

template <T>
struct DerivedClass 
{
    DerivedClass(const std::string& _name): name(_name) { }
};
```

Now I might create lots of these DerivedClass instances with different names and template types and store them in an array using their BaseClass.

```
std::vector<BaseClass*> array;
array.push_back(new DerivedClass<TABC>("abc"));
array.push_back(new DerivedClass<TDEF>("def"));
...
```

This is pretty standard runtime polymorphism.

However, when I have a new layer of functionality that is type-specific to add and don't want this new layer to be coupled in both directions, I end up having to do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void method(DerivedClass<T>* object) { }

void callMethod(BaseClass* object)
{
    // this is the logic I'm trying to move up a layer

    if (object->name == "abc")        method<TABC>(object);
    else if (object->name == "def")   method<TDEF>(object);
}
```

Each of these methods has to have the same list of run-time strings to compile-time types to convert, which means adding a new type requires a lot of changes.

If I was to assume the new layer would only support specific options known at compile-time (as is the case here anyway), then it would be feasible to add new types at runtime, but not be able to use them in this layer, which would be fine.

My current thinking is if I was to introduce a virtual method to the class hierarchy that took a function pointer, I could register the function pointers for each method in the second layer based on specific compile-time types (ideally only specified once), kind of like a double dispatch type method.

Any thoughts, suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you move the template to the base?

Comment: I do need to be able to generically store this data heterogeneously so I can use polymorphism for other use cases unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need that link to call the specific template version based on a string, the best you can do is have a dictionary of `string`->`lambda function` and use the string as a lookup to get a `function<>` to call. This avoids the nested `if`s and it's relatively easy to maintain, both at compile time (the default list) and at runtime (any changes are just array changes).

Comment: Thanks, that's along the lines of what I was thinking. The question is how to build these lists. If I were to have multiple of these string -> function lists, I'd only really want to specify the functions I were to use once and the types once, then do an all <-> all mapping to build all permutations? (Also can't use c++11 in this application yet).

Comment: Use a macro to build the function objects, and insert the template parameter in the function name to ensure uniqueness. Lambda functions are nothing more than normal functions with no name (ie a compiler generated name). You should however reconsider your arbitrary limitation, C++11 is 4 years old. If you can't use it now when can you?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than steal Sean Parent's thunder I'll direct you to this talk which will show you how to achieve this cleanly, safely and simply.

The technique is called 'polymorphism as an implementation detail'. It has transformed the way I write code.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil